# What is the difference between uppercase "-E" switch and lowercase "-e" in perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

How does the perl switches "-E" and "-e" differ from each other? In this example they works exactly the same — executes the command after the switch:

```
$ perl -e 'print "$_\n" foreach 1..2'
1
2
$ perl -E 'print "$_\n" foreach 1..2'
1
2
```

Comment: When in doubt, `perl -h` is a quick way to check switches: `-E like -e, but enables all optional features`

Comment: This was downvoted, but it's a good question. I had looked in `man perlrun`, but that only told me "See feature". And searching for "feature" in that man page didn't bring anything useful. Only in the answers below did I realize that "feature" is a pragma, and so it would be explained in `perldoc feature`.

Answer (score 13):

This is explained in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> **-E commandline**
>   behaves just like **-e**, except that it implicitly enables all optional features (in the main compilation unit). See feature.

The "See feature." refers to the documentation for the `feature` pragma, which you can read by typing [`perldoc feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

Answer (score 7):

`-E` unlike `-e` enables [**features**](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#AVAILABLE-FEATURES)

You can check what these are using `Deparse` module (following is for perl 5.16),

```
perl -MO=Deparse -E 1
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
```

Comment: `say` feature is often used in command line so `perl -e 'print "$_\n" foreach 1..2'` can be written more shortly as `perl -e 'say foreach 1..2'`

Comment: `-E` in the second one

Comment: @RobEarl tnx for comment, that should be `perl -E 'say foreach 1..2'`

Answer (score 3):

From Perldoc:http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

**•-e commandline :**

may be used to enter one line of program. If -e is given, Perl will not look for a filename in the argument list. Multiple -e commands may be given to build up a multi-line script. Make sure to use semicolons where you would in a normal program.

**•-E commandline** :

behaves just like -e, except that it implicitly enables all optional features (in the main compilation unit). See [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).